# Split a text to words with regex_findall

Tags: ansible, jinja2

what I am trying to do is to split a text into words.
I do not want to split it only by space but from other delimiters such as "=", and I do not want to split when there is a dot (.) because I want to keep IPs as a whole word.
An example of a file that contains the words I want to split is

```
> cat myconfig.xtx
key1=192.168.0.1
key2 = 192.168.0.2
key3="192.168.0.3"
key4 = "192.168.0.4"
```

from the terminal, I am running something like

```
grep -oE '(\w|\.)+' mycongig.txt
```

and it is running as expected, even if I do not fully understand why :)
But when I am trying to use it in jinja2 template with regex_findall I can not make it work.

I have tried something like this in ansible (among several other tries)

```
- name: Split words
  debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('file', item) | regex_findall('(\\w|\\.)+') }}"
  loop: "{{ files }}"
```

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Comment: According your description it looks like more that you like to lookup a key value stores, an IP database. And you like read out the IP addresses from that store or database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map *regex_findall*, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ lookup('file', 'mycongig.txt').splitlines()|
                 map('regex_findall', '[\\w\\.]+')|
                 list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - - key1
    - 192.168.0.1
  - - key2
    - 192.168.0.2
  - - key3
    - 192.168.0.3
  - - key4
    - 192.168.0.4
```

Comment: Hello Vladimir, thank you for your reply.
Unfortunately, this is not what I am looking for. 

I can do it with just .split('=') if I had only a file with key-value pairs. 
I want a general solution that will split everything into words without splitting and the IPs . I am sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.

Or maybe I didn't understand your answer and what you are suggesting is working in all cases? I didn't try it yet

Comment: Hello, laxris. You're welcome.  I've updated the answer. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: yeap, this is working exactly as I want, thank you very much! :)